# Detail on Portmanteau theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(\mu_n)_n$ and $\mu$ be probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}^d,B(\mathbb{R}^d))$.

In Portmanteau theorem, one can prove that $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if and only if for all bounded, lower semicontinuous functions $f$ we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)d\mu(x) \leq \liminf_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)d\mu_n(x),$$ this is true because, without loss of generality, we can assume $f \geq 0$ (we can take, for the general case, $f=f^+-f^-$) and using Fatou's lemma, $\liminf_n \mu_n(O) \geq \mu(O)$ for every open $O$ and that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mu(f>x)dx$$ we will obtain the result.

So, my question is, do we have the same result if we only suppose that $f$ is bounded and lower semi continuous $\mu$ a.e which means that $\mu(Q)=1$ where $Q$ is the set of points where $f$ is lower semicontinuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Assume without loss of generality that $f\ge0$, since by the boundedness of $f$, we can always subtract the constant $\inf f$. Define

$$ g_k(x) := \inf\Big\{f(y) + k\|x-y\|\,:\,y\in\mathbb R^d\Big\}.$$

Clearly, $0\le g_k(x) \le g_{k+1}(x)$, and by taking $y=x$ we see $g_k(x) \le f(x)$. Moreover, $g_k$ is continuous: if $x,z\in\mathbb R^d$, then for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$,

$$g_k(x) \le f(y) + k\|x-y\| \le \Big[f(y) + k\|z-y\|\Big] + k\|x-z\|.$$

Taking infimum over $y$, we find

$$ g_k(x) \le g_k(z) + k\|x-z\|,$$

which then implies $|g_k(x)-g_k(z)| \le k|x-z|$, and so $g_k$ is continuous as claimed. Let $g(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}g_k(x)$. If $x\in Q$ (the set of points where $f$ is lower semicontinuous) and $\epsilon>0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x) \le f(y) + \epsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$. Hence, if $\|x-y\|<\delta$,

$$ f(y) + k\|x-y\| \ge f(y) \ge f(x) - \epsilon,$$

and if $\|x-y\|>\delta$,

$$ f(y) + k\|x-y\| \ge f(y) + k\delta \ge k\delta \ge f(x) - \epsilon $$

for $k$ sufficiently large. This shows, for $k$ sufficiently large, $f_k(x) \ge f(x) - \epsilon$, and so letting $k\to\infty$ we see that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in Q$.

Now for any $k$, since $g_k$ is continuous, we have

$$ \int g_k\, d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_k\, d\mu_n \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} f \, d\mu_n.$$

Letting $k\to\infty$ and applying the monotone convergence theorem we deduce

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^d} f\, d\mu = \int_Q f\, d\mu = \int_Q g \, d\mu = \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_Q g_k\, d\mu \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^d} f\, d\mu_n.$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: I think in the line $4,$ $y$ should be equal to $x$ not $0.$ Is this Baire's theorem for semicontinuous functions?

Comment: 1. You're right, I have edited. 2. It seems related, although it's not quite the same since $f$ being semicontinuous only $\mu$-a.e. is quite a bit weaker than being semicontinuous ($\mu$ could be supported on a singleton, for instance). I adapted this proof from one I've seen for the usual portmanteau theorem.

Comment: I have one last question, and I will appreciate if you can help me, if $f$ is semicontinuous $a.e,$ let $M=\sup_x |f(x)|$and if we consider $f1_Q$ which is lower semicontinuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (since $0$ is continuous and $f_{|Q}$ (restriction) is semicontinuous) and writing $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(f+M)1_Qd\mu=\int_0^{+\infty} \mu((f+M)1_Q>y)dy$ and using the fact that $\forall y>0,$ the set $(f+M)1_Q>y$ is open so we can use $\mu(O) \leq \liminf_n\mu(O)$ and we conclude using Fatou's lemma and that $(f+M)1_Q \leq f+M$

Comment: The issue is $f1_Q$ is not necessarily lower semicontinuous. For example, take $f=2-1_{\mathbb Q}$, i.e. $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=2$ otherwise. Then $f$ is lower semicontinuous on $\mathbb Q$, but $f1_{\mathbb Q}$ is lower semicontinuous only on $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: What about taking $f1_Q+M1_{Q^c}$ (considering partition)

Comment: There may well be some clever choice of function which works, but this is by no means obvious and you would have to carefully prove the function is always lower semicontinuous.